# What's the difference between "bliss" and "happiness"?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between *bliss* and *happiness*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bliss is a great deal stronger than happiness. You can be happy because it's not raining today, or because you found your glasses. But *bliss* is reserved for a state of complete, perfect happiness, such as what you may experience by finding your soulmate or having a transcendent spiritual experience.

Comment: +1 - Concise, but clear.

Answer (score 2):

*Happiness* is an emotion while *bliss* is a condition of the mind.

Emotions occur at an excited state of the mind and anything that's at an excited state comes back to ground state. Whereas *bliss* is a general state of the mind by itself, it doesn't take anything to do in order to attain bliss - it's just there. Whereas to feel happy, you need to do something like getting good marks, earning money, making friends,and so on.

The path to attain a state of bliss is through self contentment, where all your actions are done without ego involved - consequences don't matter but your willingness to do something is what matters.

Comment: So it means, we should be look to get into a state of blissfulness and not chasing the next thing that will give us the shot of happiness.

Answer (score 2):

About 3 years ago I checked into the ER with an obstructed bladder (due to kidney stones).  The pain was unimaginable.  Thankfully, the ER people recognized right away how much pain I was in and got me into a room right away.  Several nurses got quickly to work, placing a "Foley catheter" in my urethra, draining the accumulated urine, and removing the pressure.

What I then felt was utter, total *bliss* -- a feeling of such incredible contentment and serenity that I cared not one whit that I was lying on a table with my pants down around my ankles and a tube hanging out.  The sensation slowly diminished, but not for several hours.

I strongly suspect that true *bliss* cannot be achieved without some preceding hardship.

Answer (score 0):

Bliss is felt in the heart and as if in our blood. It is state of happiness when asking for anything is foreign to it, even we do not ask for spiritual virtues. It is all in all.

Comment: This answer doesn't clear things up at all. I have no idea what you mean.